# How can I get values count from wp_commentmeta?

Tags: comment-form, comment-meta

I am using ACF Plugin in my wordpress site, and I have added radio buttons in comment form, like reactions. 
[image: comment form]

it's saving results in wp_commentmeta like this;

[image: wp_commentmeta]

it's working very good but I want to display results in single post page block below the post content like this ;

sad: 44

funny: 11

hate: 23

good: 0

is it possible? Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following function in your Theme's functions.php and then put `<?php echo tnc_reactions_count($post->ID); ?>` in your single.php to output the numbers. Let me know if it works as I have not tested it completely.

```
function tnc_reactions_count($post_id){
    global $wpdb;
    $comments_table = $wpdb->prefix.'comments';
    $commentsmeta_table = $wpdb->prefix.'commentmeta';
    $get_post_comments = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $comments_table WHERE comment_post_ID='$post_id'", OBJECT );
    $funny_total = 0;
    $sad_total = 0;
    $hate_total = 0;
    $good_total = 0;

    foreach ($get_post_comments as $key => $value) {
        $comment_id = $value->comment_ID;
        $query_reaction = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $commentsmeta_table WHERE `comment_id`='$comment_id' AND `meta_key`='comments_reactions'", OBJECT );

        foreach ($query_reaction as $key => $value) {

            $get_reaction = $value->meta_value;

            switch ($get_reaction) {
                case 'funny':
                    $funny_total += 1;
                    break;

                case 'sad':
                    $sad_total += 1;
                    break;

                case 'hate':
                    $hate_total += 1;
                    break;

                case 'good':
                    $good_total += 1;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    $output = '<h3>Reactions</h3>';
    $output .= 'Funny: '.$funny_total;
    $output .= 'Sad: '.$sad_total;
    $output .= 'Hate: '.$hate_total;
    $output .= 'Good: '.$good_total;

    return $output;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: thank you very much for answer, but always "0"  do I need to change any part of function?

Comment: There was a mistake. Please try again with the edited code.

Comment: It's same brother

Comment: Ok. I'll test it and post again

Comment: can I add the count numbers in postmeta? when users write a comment and selected reaction? with **update_post_meta** ?

Comment: Code updated. This version should work.

Comment: Sir my last question; can I use $wpdb->prepare(); in those $wpdb->results(); ?